# React Not allowed to load local resource:

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use the react-awesome-slider but I keep getting the 'Not allowed to load local resource:' error. I don't get why this is a problem when I can use my local images normally as a background image, which I have one, or using the normal image tag. I'm trying to add a carousel of some sort but every different type of carousel I try I have the same problem. Trying to use a carousel is the only time I've ever experienced this. For the src, I have tried using relative and actual file paths and neither work. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share your code? I assume you are trying to access files from your local machine, like `file:///`

Comment: No website can ever load a local file of any kind, that would be an immense security hole (any page could read your entire hard disk). The exceptions are if the HTML itself was loaded from a local file or if the user explicitly picked a file with an input file control.